# Dump all email metadata from Microsoft Exchange

Tags: email, exchange, email-server, database

I'm trying to get a dump of the following information from a hypothetical Exchange server:

- Email Sender(s)
- Email Recipient(s)
- Time Sent

I'm a real Exchange novice here, but I found [this article](http://techgenix.com/Understanding-Exchange-Information-Store/) that says some of that information may be in transaction logs. I've also found a few PowerShell scripts that conduct searches, but nothing that does what I'm looking for.

I have no problem parsing plaintext to get this information if it's in logs, but I don't know where to look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With so less information its not easy to give you a full option here. However what you can do is to use powershell and searching the Message Tracking logfiles. For example

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) | Where-Object {$_.recipients -like "*@gmail.com"}
```

Which will show all messages in the past hour for gmail.com users.

More infos can be found inside the Microsoft documentation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124926(v=exchg.160).aspx).

You might therefore start with something like:

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) | FT Recipients, TimeStamp, MessageSubject > "C:\temp\MySearchResult.txt"
```

or

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start "2008-12-09" | Select Recipients, Timestamp, Sender, @{Name='Recipients';Expression={[string]::join(";", ($_.Recipients))}} | Export-CSV c:\Temp\MailStat.csv
```

Just to give you some options.

*Keep noted that the results are limited for the first 1,000 events as written [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124926(v=exchg.160).aspx)! So you need to specify some smaller time frames to export everything.*

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will read up on Message Tracking logfiles.